# New region or module_invoke?

Tags: theming

I'm developing a simple site and want to keep everything as simple as possible, without any unnecessary performance lost or redundat code. Design is pretty static, therefore no need lot of regions for a lot of blocks. Currentlty I have have only one region and 2 templates - one for front page and second for other pages - that's all I need so far.

But there is a new block generated by Language switcher module that shows a select input for switching languages. What's more efficient way of displaying a block - by creating new region and placing this block into, or by inserting it directly into page.tpl.php template with `module_invoke()` function?

Comment: I guess this is more of a personal preference. For real customized theming, I rather like the the ```module_invoke``` method. Also, ```module_invoke``` is more transportable through environments unless you use ```features_extra``` which can capture block settings.

Comment: As long as you're caching properly it's kind of a moot point